# Should functions be used as means to organize code, even if the function is only executed once?

Tags: javascript, performance, coding-efficiency

I often find myself chunking code into functions just as a means to make it more readable.

Example:

```
// Returns 4 random menus
function getRandomMenus(menus_in){
  //Return random menus
}

// Assign random decision times for players 1 and 2
function getTimes(){
  // Return random times
}
```

But then these functions are only executed once (when initiating the program):

```
menus = getRandomMenus(all_menus);
all_times = getTimes();
```

This seems inefficient, but the alternative seems harder to follow (even for me, who wrote the code), and this is even more so true when the functions become more complicated than in the above examples.

Even if this is inefficient (which I feel like it is) is it ok to sacrifice efficiency for the sake of readability?

Comment: There is a good site about this question: https://refactoring.guru/extract-method

Comment: @SlawaEremkin Thanks! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: It is better to 'chunk into functions', because your code is easier to understand, it is closer to application logic scheme, and if you use a function more than once - it's easy to find it and edit it just in one place.

Comment: @MichałDąbrowski Your comment actually made me realize an interesting follow-up question: What if executing the code more than once results in the program running incorectly (as is the case for the example in the question, as regenerating a randomly generated array would cause problems with data storage / tracking)? Would it be best to not make it a function or insert some sort of failsafe to check if it's been done before?

Comment: @user2762533: This latest comment might make for a good question on its own, but a quick answer is that you could easily write a `once` function decorator that will cache the result of the first call and always return that value on subsequent ones.  But if you reach for this to avoid logic problems, you've probably selected a bad tool.  It's mostly useful as a way to solve performance problems on expensive calls whose result are fixed.

Comment: *is it ok to sacrifice efficiency for the sake of readability?* Yes, it is, especially when the alleged efficiency is illusory.

Comment: just bare in mind that in most programming languages including JS when you pass a parameter you are creating a copy of the original object and if your code has some large objects to be passed it is possibly better to declare this variables globally